# await usr.add_roles(role) Missing Permissions

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to manage roles for user with `await usr.add_roles(role)` on discord.py and I am getting:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Where do I set that permission?

Comment: Just give the bot `manage roles` or `admin` permissions **on the discord server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

- First make sure the usr's top tole is above the top role of the bot by going to Server Settings > Roles
- Make sure your bot has the Manage Roles permission by going to Server Settings > Roles then clicking on a role your bot has